# Hibernate criteria group results by date from timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, date

I have table with timestamp column and want to create Hibernate criteria projection to group me results only by date from that timestamp column (the results in database are YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss).
I know that I have to use `Projection.sqlGroupProjection`but not quiet sure hot to do so.

Also, is it possible to write same projection for both MySQL and Oracle ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using the `date` function inside your `sqlGroupProjection`:

```
Projections.sqlGroupProjection("date(timestampField) as myDate", "myDate", new String[] { "myDate" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE })
```

Comment: And that part is failing on Oracle but works on MySQL. On Oracle its written with trunc(timestampField) but it gives me error uknown identifier

Comment: Are you using myDate for something else? (For example to order)

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you need to order by that column, you need to create an alias for that column

```
Projections.alias(Projections.sqlGroupProjection(
    "trunc(timestampField) as myDate", "myDate", 
            new String[] { "myDate" }, 
            new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE }), "myDateOrder"))
```

Then you can use:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("myDateOrder"));
```

*Note: My answer is based on **nuno** answer adding the order capability.*